# Can Integral Trees be Sailed?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gas-giants

In the book *The Integral Trees* by Larry Niven, he presents people living in a novel environment. There is a neutron star (quite old and so cooled off mostly) around a more ordinary star.  And orbiting the neutron star their is a gas giant planet. The gas giant's atmosphere (and a little bit of rock and soil and such) has been mostly pulled off to form a gas torus around the neutron star.

The neutron star is called LeVoy's star, shortened to Voy. The gas giant is called Goldblatt's world, shortened to Gold.

The mid-line of the gas torus is where the air pressure is largest. It's also where there is the most water, available rocks and dirt, and living plants and animals. So most life in the gas ring wants to stay close to this line.

[image]

There is a species of tree that grows at least 100 km long. Tides keep such trees radial to the neutron star. Because the torus rotates more slowly as you move out from Voy, there is constant wind at each end of the tree.

[image]

Sorry for my limited ability to draw. The trees have tufts of green foliage at each end. The wind is blowing to the right at the top, and the left at the bottom. The straight trunk in the middle is up to about 100 km long.

The wind blows because the gas rotates slower at larger radius. So the center of the tree is orbiting at the same speed as the air at that radius. The outer end of the tree is orbiting the same speed as its middle, which is too fast for the larger radius. The inner end is rotating too slowly for the smaller radius. It feels backward wind at the outer end and forward wind at the inner end. So the tufts tend in the corresponding direction.

Some people live on one of these threes. In the story, a substantial part of the plot derives from the tree being too far out. They are experiencing a drought.

My question is, **could they sail the tree?** Would the following work?

Suppose they are too far out.  They decrease the size of the tuft on the side they want to move towards.  They use ropes to compress the tuft on the inward end. The wind then pushes harder on the outward end. This causes the tree to slow in its orbit a little. This moves it inward. When the tree is back where they want it they remove the ropes and balance the forces again. Don't want to cut away foliage because the tree would then be lopsided.

Comment: You cannot "slow in the orbit a little" without changing the orbit. Orbits are not railroads.

Comment: I don't think Goldblatt's World was within the torus of air.  It orbited just outside the neutron star's Roche limit, but it's atmosphere was pulled in closer to the star to form the torus.

Comment: Never mind.  Checking a wiki article, it mentions that the Admiralty from Smoke Ring is in the L4 position of Voy and Gold, which requires Gold to also be within the ring.

Comment: @AlexP  I'm pretty sure I still remember my high school physics. An unbalanced force, yada yada. I am saying it changes orbits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this should be possible, yes. The way a sail works is that it fills the concave side with pressure, exerting a force that is roughly perpendicular to the sail instead of one that is pushing the direction of the wind. It would have changed the direction of the force on the tufts.

[image: My even worse diagram]

I don't remember anybody trying this.

Comment: Be careful about the direction of your force. When in an orbit: slow=>low, low=>fast, fast=>high, high=>slow. So if you want a higher orbit, you have to go faster. Don't try to go up.

Comment: @Brianorca, Point made. To get to a higher orbit, you want to go slower, so you're right, the sail would be at a perpendicular to the one I drew, and you would want it to be on the other end of the tree.

Comment: Correction: to go higher, you must add velocity, but once you get higher, you will be moving more slowly than if you had stayed put. (The extra speed has been turned into altitude.) If you slow down, you will go lower. But yes, a sail perpendicular to the wind, on the higher tuft, will speed you up and give you a higher orbit.

Comment: @Brianorca, "to go higher, you must add velocity," That's not how orbital dynamics work. You apply thrust, but higher orbits always have a lower velocity than the lower ones.

Comment: But you said "To get to a higher orbit, you want to go slower" which is reversed causation. You must go faster to reach a higher orbit, and after you do get to the new apogee, you are now moving slower. You need more *initial* velocity to go up the hill, but you slow down on the way to the top.

Comment: @Brianorca, You're describing a Hohmann maneuver. I'm describing low thrust relative orbit transfer, as used to reboost ISS. Both have the same effect, but the Hohmann maneuver hides the overall vector of the thrust by performing it at two different parts in the orbit.

Comment: A low thrust orbit raise still works by speeding up, even if it's a little at a time, and even if you lose velocity as it raises. (Thrust in prograde.)

Comment: @Brianorca, It sounds like you're suggesting that an increase in potential energy is the same thing as "speeding up." LEO speed is 7.5km/s, geosync is 3km/s. That's not speeding up.

Comment: At the moment you apply thrust, in order to reach geosync, you must be thrusting in the prograde direction, even if you are doing it in mm/s/s at a time, it's still a speedup in that moment. It is only when you start reaching that higher altitude when you slow down. If you slow down without raising altitude, you will lose altitude.

Comment: We're talking about the same thing, but you're talking about the result (high and slow) and I'm talking about the action needed to get there.

Comment: @Brianorca, I think you're right. If either of us actually has to perform this maneuver, we can revisit it. :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the subplots of the book (or maybe the sequel) involved a natural process where the tree split in two, so that one half would be sent to a lower orbit.

Sailing the tree should also have some effect. Sailing involves taking advantage of a difference in fluid speed, such as between water and wind for a sailboat. The trees are large enough to see substantial speed difference between the top and bottom tufts. Adding airfoils, or even just more drag, to one or the other tuft should slowly alter the orbit. But you would have to be careful to not overpower the tidal force that aligns the trees vertically in the gravity field.